# Odd P2P device delays suspend by 10 seconds

Tags: networking, wireless, suspend, systemd

I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 16.10 to 17.04 and I noticed a 10 second delay when I put my laptop to sleep.

The following is a part of syslog, after pressing the button. The extra newline added by me separated when I press the sleep button (11:12:53) and the computer actually falls asleep (11:13:03).

```
Aug 19 11:12:53 lynx systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
Aug 19 11:12:53 lynx systemd[1]: Starting Suspend...
Aug 19 11:12:53 lynx wpa_supplicant[1301]: nl80211: deinit ifname=p2p-dev-wlan0 disabled_11b_rates=0
Aug 19 11:12:53 lynx wpa_supplicant[1301]: nl80211: deinit ifname=wlan0 disabled_11b_rates=0

Aug 19 11:13:03 lynx systemd-sleep[2458]: Selected interface 'p2p-dev-wlan0'
Aug 19 11:13:03 lynx systemd-sleep[2458]: 'SUSPEND' command timed out.
Aug 19 11:13:03 lynx systemd-sleep[2465]: /lib/systemd/system-sleep/wpasupplicant failed with error code 254.
Aug 19 11:13:03 lynx systemd-sleep[2458]: Suspending system...
```

I don't use any Ad-Hoc WiFi networks. How do I get rid of this `p2p-dev-wlan0` interface? I guess thats why the computer waits 10 seconds. I can't find the interface anywhere.

Comment: This seems related:  https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=835648